# jquery error replacement image is not replacing

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to show a ticked image if validation true if not an X mark image and an error message next to it.

1. Refresh the screen and click submit button, all the fields are getting validated, showing ‘X’ image and an error message next to the input field.
2. Enter a valid data- then ok tick mark image is loaded and error message was removed
   If I remove the entered data, error message is coming back but left the tick mark as it is.

I need to remove the tick mark and replace with “X” mark.

I am trying to implement [Milk example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/).

```
 $('#iPaySearchPolicyForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin     
    rules: {
        policyNumber: {
            required: true,
            alphanumeric: true
        },
        phLastName: {
            required: true,
            letterswithbasicpunc: true,
        },
        zip: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        policyNumber: {
            required: "Please enter a username "
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //error.insertAfter(element);
        error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
    },
    success: function (label) {
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    },
});
```

Stylesheet

```
#iPaySearchPolicyForm label.error {
    background:url("images/unchecked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EA5200;
}
#iPaySearchPolicyForm label.checked {
    background:url("images/checked.gif") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="policyNumber" class=" control-label ">Policy Number</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="text-input form-control " type="text " name="policyNumber " id="policyNumber " />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="phLastName " class=" control-label ">Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="text-input form-control " type="text " name="phLastName " id="phLastName " />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="zip " class=" control-label ">Zip</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="text-input form-control " id="zip " type="text " name="zip " maxlength="5 " size="5 " />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button " name="search " id="search " class="btn btn-success ">Search Policy</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ifound the issue. Below code needs to be added to the validate method.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent().next().find("." + errorClass).removeClass("checked");
        },
```